# stackoverflowerror in jbpm6

Tags: jboss7.x, stack-overflow, jbpm

I am using JBPM6 and I am getting weird stackoverflowerrors, rather stumped at this stage, so perhaps something has similar experience and can point me in the right direction.

Instance1:

```
2015-08-19 20:23:47,033 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) EJB 3.1 FR 13.3.3: BMT bean ProcessBean should complete transaction before returning.
2015-08-19 20:23:47,038 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ProcessBean for method public abstract long com.vfml.vfmladmin.migration.ejb.ProcessLocal.startProcess(com.vfml.vfmladmin.migration.model.MigrationOrgList) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB 3.1 FR 13.3.3: BMT bean ProcessBean should complete transaction before returning.
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.checkStatelessDone(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:88) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:108) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:82) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.vfml.vfmladmin.migration.ejb.ProcessLocal$$$view19.startProcess(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at com.vfml.vfmladmin.migration.web.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:93) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar:2012-08-06 19:12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:95) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:449) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.UncloseableOutputStream.write(UncloseableOutputStream.java:39) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:77) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.UninterruptibleOutputStream.write(UninterruptibleOutputStream.java:59) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:125) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.UninterruptibleOutputStream.write(UninterruptibleOutputStream.java:87) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.safeFlush(WriterHandler.java:162) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.flush(WriterHandler.java:133) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.doPublish(ExtHandler.java:92) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:70) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:64) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:283) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:291) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:291) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:291) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:291) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:291) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:291) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:649) [jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar:1.2.2.GA]
    at org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:205)
    at com.vfml.vfmladmin.migration.service.AbstractDomainService.executeWorkItem(AbstractDomainService.java:75) [classes:]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:56) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:124) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.triggerCompleted(JoinInstance.java:259) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.internalTrigger(JoinInstance.java:62) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.executeStrategy(SplitInstance.java:117) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.internalTrigger(SplitInstance.java:63) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.java:44) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:286) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:265) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:275) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.workItemAborted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:329) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.signalEvent(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:315) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.signalEvent(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:399) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.abortWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:166) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at com.vfml.vfmladmin.migration.service.AbstractDomainService.executeWorkItem(AbstractDomainService.java:101) [classes:]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:56) [drools-persistence-jpa-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:124) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.triggerCompleted(JoinInstance.java:259) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.JoinInstance.internalTrigger(JoinInstance.java:62) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.executeStrategy(SplitInstance.java:117) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.internalTrigger(SplitInstance.java:63) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.java:44) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:286) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:265) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:275) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.workItemAborted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:329) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.signalEvent(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:315) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.signalEvent(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:399) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:352) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.executeStrategy(SplitInstance.java:117) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SplitInstance.internalTrigger(SplitInstance.java:63) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:155) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:337) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:296) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.java:44) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:286) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:265) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:275) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.workItemAborted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:329) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.signalEvent(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:315) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.signalEvent(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:399) [jbpm-flow-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
```

Thanks for your help -

Comment: It seems to stem from AbstractDomainService.executeWorkItem() - http://pastebin.com/yxZ2UmRC

Comment: It looks like the stacktrace is occuring when you are trying to start a process. Can you share your code on how you are attempting to start it?

Comment: I can indeed mike - http://pastebin.com/qcKFQ25P